# Play 2.6, play2-maven-plugin, custom loader, MessagesApi injector issues

Tags: playframework

I’m struggling to get a play application to start which is being migrated to play 2.6

My searches to find a solution have failed.

I have extended GuiceApplicationLoader and I’m using play2-maven-plugin

```
7) No implementation for play.api.i18n.MessagesApi was bound.
  while locating play.api.i18n.MessagesApi
    for the 1st parameter of play.i18n.MessagesApi.<init>(MessagesApi.java:27)
  while locating play.i18n.MessagesApi
    for the 1st parameter of play.core.j.DefaultJavaContextComponents.<init>(JavaAction.scala:172)
  at play.api.inject.BuiltinModule$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$1.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:81):
Binding(interface play.core.j.JavaContextComponents to ConstructionTarget(class play.core.j.DefaultJavaContextComponents)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)

8) No implementation for play.api.mvc.FlashCookieBaker was bound.

9) No implementation for play.api.mvc.SessionCookieBaker was bound.
```

I have included the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
    <artifactId>play_2.12</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MessagesApi is now in a separate Play module: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.6.17/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/i18n/I18nModule.scala

This is included in the default Play reference.conf: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.6.17/framework/src/play/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L817

By default, this reference.conf should be loaded as long as the dependency is on the classpath, so it should just work. I was overwriting play.modules.enabled in  application.conf

```
play.modules { enabled = []
```